# hola me podrian explicar como puedo imprmir esto para que se vea como un mini listado bonito

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

ya avía echo esta pregunta pero no se porque no se publico.

me gustaria imprimir una serie de titulos con este mismos estilo, lo e intentado hacer con **setw** pero no se hace bien, nose porque, y me **gustaria que me ayudan talves no haciendo una sintaxis tan compleja, si podrian ayudarme con una sintaxis pues humilde porque soy principiante aun en c++**

```
cout<<left<<setw(10)<<"Tipo turismo"<<left<<setw(22)<<"Tipo persona"<<setw(14)<<"Genero"<<left<<setw(10)<<right<<"Genero"<<
left<<setw(10)<<"Fecha"<<left<<setw(16)<<"Peticiones"<<endl;
```

otra cosa es si podrían darme ideas con respecto al color, yo e intentado digamos con la función de la librería de windows.h **color(hConsole, 6);** pero pasa que esta función modifica el color de todo el código que se allá puesto abajo de la función, entonces quería igual a ver si me ayudaban a crear una forma diferente para agregar color a los títulos sin que la info de adentro se me modifique

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay una respuesta en stackexchange [aquí](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191032/console-based-table-structure) en inglés. Está el detalle del código (el link al repo de Github) y las mejoras al mismo. Sería interesante un aporte así en español.

Comment: demasiado duro de entender, con que me ayuden a poner esos titulos de la forma de **nombre**    **edad**   **pasatiempo**  ** sujerencias**

Comment: pero con los espacios entre palabras no se muestraaaaa, y nose porque al menos con eso podrias ayudarme, quiero que al menos esos titulos se muestren bonitos pero se imprimen pegados y nose de que otra menera que no sea con /t puedo hacerlo

Comment: Ejecuté tu código en un compilador de `c++` en línea y si se muestra los espacios. Está maximizada la ventana del terminal en donde se muestra el resultado?

Comment: no la verdad no esta mas pequeña de lo normal

Comment: era eso gracias